# Show that the rank of g is equal to dimV/2 under the following conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Reviewing some linear algebra problems and came across this example.

Let V be a vector space and let g:V -> V be a linear mapping. Show that if g composed with g is equal to {0}, rank g = dimV/2.

So far I've figured out that g composed with g equals zero, the nullity of g composed with g is equal to all V, so the dimension is dimV and rank of g composed with g equals zero.

Beyond this I'm stuck.

Comment: What if $g=\text{zero operator}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the claim is false. Take for example $g=0$, then $g\circ g=0$ but $\mathrm{rank}(g)=0$.

What is true is that $\mathrm{rank}(g)\leq\mathrm{dim}(V)/2$. To see this, we use the following theorem: $$\dim(V)=\dim(\mathrm{null}(g))+\mathrm{rank}(g).$$
If $\mathrm{rank}(g)>V/2$, then $\dim(\mathrm{null}(g))<V/2$. Consequently, the range of $g$, which has dimension $\mathrm{rank}(g)$, cannot be contained in the null space of $g$ and therefore $g\circ g$ is not $0$.